# Recording with audio input MacBook Air

Tags: audio, macbook-air

I'm trying to record analogue stereo sound with my MacBookAir. The external mic is plugged to the headphones jack, but it is not being shown in the System Preferences. I did a little bit of research, and there is some rumor, that the headphone jack only supports digital-in for mics.

Is there a built-in way to use the analogue stereo sound without purchasing an external converter or a new mic? With my old MacBook 2,1 it was usual for me to do this, but with my new MacBook Air 4,1 it seems to be a tough task.

Comment: Yea- I love the way Apple tech just goes in with the new and out with the old. It forces its community to stay up to date..which is very nice; but very expensive.

Answer (score 5):

My MacBook Air mid 2012 with OS X 10.8.3 does have the External Audio-IN capability.

[image]

It is just bit hidden and not well explained by Big Apple.

As you can read it suggest to use the iPhone headset (with microphone.

Digging in to that one finds out that it is the audio plug (hardware) that is special.

[image]

One could be stubborn in wanting to use your microphone and not the iPhone headset version, so this is the solution for that.

A audio splitter from 4 to 3 rings :)

[image]

I found [stores in Europ](http://eu.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/Audio-Cables/35mm-4-Position-to-2x-3-Position-35mm-Headset-Splitter-Adapter-Male-to-Female~MUYHSMFF)e (for about €10), but sure you can find it where you are.

Comment: If you're like me and don't know your way around the mac, first screenshot is in apple icon > about this mac > overview tab > system report.

Answer (score 0):

Macbook air is castrated as much as it can be.... I don't know what's you goal for using stereo input at all, but if I were you, I'd buy some usb audio interface, which has normal inputs with btw normal impedance (!). But it's just because I used to make some demos with plugged guitar for example =) after a while everybody goes to audio interfaces, to get better quality and latency anyway =)

Comment: and you can certainly recommend some thread which clarifies the question of which audio interface is reasonable?

Comment: well macbook air doesn't have analog input =) so sorry, only way to go is to have external audio interface..